# Dash Scattermapbox without custom data

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am working on a dashboard in which the user can select which datapoints are displayed on a map. In the absence of a selection I need to display the map without any added data, so just open-streetmap. Using `plotly.express.scatter_mapbox()`, i am unable to produce the desired empty map. I tried by handing over an empty pandas dataframe or no dataframe at all. Is there a solution for this problem using this function?
Thanks

Comment: It would be sufficient to specify an empty scatter plot. I think it would be possible by modifying the legend [example](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#basic-example) as follows. `fig = go.Figure();fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox());fig.update_layout(...)`;fig.show()

Comment: Thanks that produced exactly what i needed.